# Rebuilding fence - lumber questions

Tags: wood, framing, exterior, fence, lumber

I recently bought a condo with a 11'x13' patio with a wooden privacy fence. The fence is in pretty bad shape so I want redo it while we are locked down in our houses. I've read up a ton and just want to confirm what I know before I purchase all of the materials. This fence is on concrete, I assume that is crucial information.

[image]

Here is my current materials list:

- 2 6x6 posts
- 4 4x6 posts
- 22 2x4
- 80 1x6 redwood fencing planks
- EasyGate no sag gate kit
- Galvanized post bases for all of the post
- Camo Deck Fastener System
- 2.5" deck screws

My main questions are:

- If the fence is on concrete and nothing will be touching the ground, do I need pressure treated lumber? I was thinking maybe for the posts only but even then they will be raised by the post base. For sure the framing I'm thinking I can just use normal 2x4 wood? Also I plan on painting the posts and staining the planks so do I even need pressure treated?
- I know the planks will have their screws hidden because of the camo system, however for the general framing portion of the fence, do I need to do anything to protect the screws? I assume I should avoid having the screws facing up so that water doesn't collect but other than that do I need to seal them somehow?

I appreciate your help in advance, thanks!

Comment: Location (rain frequency & humidity) is a big factor. Where I live, central florida, USA, everything exposed to the weather should be PT.

Comment: I live in Southern California. Mostly dry but the past 2 years we have seen a ton of rain, more than usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wood isn't pressure-treated just because it may touch the ground. It's a sponge, and it'll always be damp inside unless you're in a desert. Whether you need it is your prerogative, but why would you pay a premium for redwood pickets and not use something of roughly equal longevity to support them?

Brand recommendations are off-topic here. I've removed that portion of your post.

Screws don't need to be protected. They're presumably corrosion-resistant, or they're not suitable for a fence.

*Important*: I don't know what post bases you're planning to use, but most aren't designed to hold up a fence. They're merely connectors and/or spacers. Be sure yours are up to the task.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107798/discussion-on-answer-by-isherwood-rebuilding-fence-lumber-questions).