# Structural integrity of new fence on concrete slab

Tags: framing, fence, structural, anchor

I recently bought a condo with a 11'x13' patio with a wooden privacy fence. The fence is in pretty bad shape so I want redo it with new wood in a more modern design by doing horizontal planks. I posted another question about materials ([Rebuilding fence - lumber questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192257/rebuilding-fence-lumber-questions)) and from that discussion now have questions about the structural integrity of my design. I sketched out the existing framing and proposed framing with an sky view and front view.

[image]

The main difference is that I will be increasing the size of the corner posts to 6x6 so that I can screw the horizontal planks to the framing and the post will still stick out of it. Something like (https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8c/e8/d4/8ce8d43018c740fb1c6b47f8a6a369d8.jpg). I also want to add a 4x6 post in the middle of each side to break up the long stretch of horizontal planks.

Is this plan sound? I am open to all suggestions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't clear on how the posts are anchored. Are you pouring concrete piers or doing metal mounting plates with concrete anchors? Either way, I think your plan is sound but you should also anchor the center posts which are floating in your current plan. That will add considerably more structural integrity to your fencing.
I like the 6x6 posts for strength and aesthetics.

Comment: I will be using a post base bracket with a 5/8" x 10" concrete wedge anchor. I was going to anchor all of the posts originally but was told that would reduce the structural integrity of the fence. See the comments in the linked post if you want to see more about that

Comment: I read the other post. I don't want to recreate the original post but the comment was made that you will "want rigid bases or embedded posts" I didn't see any comment that anchoring all of the posts "would reduce the structural integrity of the fence". Again the issue is lateral strength (wind forces). You have hinge points at the unanchored posts in the center of your fence. Solid fences like yours act like a sail catching wind. I would prefer that the posts were embedded but they're not. The next best thing is to attach all of the posts into the concrete with anchors.

Comment: My understanding of the comments were that using the post base would not be rigid enough and would act more as a hinge point. The current fence doesn't have an attached post in the middle as well so I figured it was true.

Comment: I may be wrong but the hinge point referred to is the vertical hinge point at the center post of each side which is not anchored. Isherwood made the comment that "you'd want continuous rails between the corner posts" which will also help prevent hinging at the center. If I were doing this I would anchor the center post and install continuous rails from corner to corner.

Comment: By a continuous rail, is a 2x4 that goes from one corner post to the next sufficient? By continuous rail I assume that means an uncut piece of wood? Would it be more secure if the wood was screwed in on top of the posts or to the side?

Comment: Continuous means uncut. 2x4s or 2x6s attached to the side of the posts should be sufficient.

Comment: Okay and just to be clear, when I said side to side I mean like one face to the other face (going above the middle post). Do you think this post base is strong enough to add a gate on the left side? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-E-Z-Base-Black-Powder-Coated-Post-Base-for-4x4-Nominal-Lumber-FPBB44/100655350

Comment: I don't see any thing in this post about "side to side" so I don't know what you're asking. Adding in a gate was not in the above post and brings in a whole new dimension regarding stability. The short answer is "no". Adding in a gate without embedded posts or without adding additional structural stability to the fence is not a good idea in my opinion. I'm not sure I can offer any better advice on this topic other than what you've already received. Good luck.